# A touch screen TV with YouTube app

Tags: television

I have two autistic children, sometimes they mirror their iPads to our TV and they get very frustrated when they try use YouTube on the TV only to find out that it's not touchscreen.

What I need is

- A TV, we still need a TV to watch in the living room
- Touchscreen
- Builtin YouTube app

I am aware of

- Endless number of touchscreen monitors NOT TVs
- Endless number of SMART TVs with builtin YouTube app

[Touchjet WAVE](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/touchjet-wave-turns-tv-into-a-touchscreen-tablet-android-television#/) turned out to be a big disappointment otherwise I would have gone for a smart TV and turned it into a touchscreen one using Touchjet WAVE.

[Apple Television](http://campusbasement.com/undecided/apple/articles/9889/apple-unveils-new-60-inch-touchscreen-television) seems to be a myth, otherwise it would have been very idle for me as my children are very familiar with iOS.

What other options do I have?

Comment: I hope you find a solution, I googled for half a day without finding anything except touchjet. I kept finding things called touch screen conversion frames, and this company http://www.u-touch.us/ but I don't know if it will actually work. Best of luck, hope someone finds something for you.

Comment: @ulkoma Do you have a size requirement?  Additionally is there a reason you are specific about it behing a TV as opposed to a monitor?  If you still have the ability to plug in your cable box via HDMI?  Also do you have a budget?